# Can't enable iCloud Music Library issue

Tags: icloud, ios, apple-music

I'm running iOS 8.4.1. When I go into to the app settings and tap to enable the iCloud Music Library, I get the `Replace` or `Merge`. After this the option reverts back to off automatically. I tried lots of times, rebooting the phone, switching airplane mode on/off, but still the same...

UPDATE: I spoke to apple support and it seems like the "iTunes in the cloud" functionality is not available for certain countries yet, so there's no way to enable the iCloud Music Library and therefore there's no way of creating playlists, saving music offline or adding a song to "my library" feature. To me that almost cripples Apple Music app... disappointing

Comment: Bogdan, check out my updated answer and see if it will work for you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also having this problem, and I also live in RO.

I have reported a bug to Apple, they asked me to install some certificates and send them logs after i was trying to activate that switch. But that was like a week or two before making 8.4.1 update so i kinda starting lose hope. Reply them back and no response since then.

It might be a problem in this country..because none of my friends can't activate it.

I have tried everything on the internet to solve my problem and **nothing**

> UPDATE:
>   I have made it, I activated by mistake following these steps:

1. Change AppStore Store from Romania to SUA
2. Go to Settings -> Music -> And switch iClound Music Library on
3. Get back to your Ro Store, and it will remain like this!!!! :)

Comment: how did you send the bug report to apple?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ **->** Sign In **->** report it there

Comment: I also think it's a country issue since, I can't enable icloud music library on iTunes on my mac either... I tried to file a bug report but I couldn't sign in with apple id, so I filed a bug report that I can't login to the bug reporter first :(

Comment: That bug report it might be only for iOS Developers if you can't sign it with Apple ID :-? but I have managed to login also with Apple ID that has no developer account on it

Comment: When trying to change stores from Ro to US I get the following error message `To change stores you must first cancel your Apple Music membership`. Did you get this one?

Comment: This also appears me but on iTunes, not on my iPhone. Are you trying to Mac or iPhone?

Comment: I tried on my iPhone and got that error message :( on iTunes I'm not aware of any way of changing the AppStore country...

Comment: Uhm... I will reproduce the steps I have made: Entered iTunesConnect app on my phone -> entered to a unlaunched app of mine I am working -> Clicked "View on the App Store" -> It asked me if i want to change stores -> Change store -> Entered to Music in Settings -> Swithced On -> Change back store